# Why can't I view 301 redirects in chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome, http, redirect, subdomain

If I curl `"google.com"`, I know it issues a `301` redirect to `http://www.google.com/`. However, I cannot see this anywhere in the networking tab on chrome. I have tried all of the following:

- Checking preserve log in the network tab
- Checking disable cache in the network tab
- Empty cache and hard reloading
- Going to `chrome://net-internals/` and clearing the cache
- Clearing all cached images and files since the beginning of time in chrome
- Specifically monitoring "Other" in the network tab

Can anyone please explain why? I am very interested.

Answer (score 3):

Just posting in case anyone else has this issue.
Without knowing the details here are two possibilities.

1. You are clicking a link that opens a new window/tab, in which case
   your developer tools window is now looking at the wrong thing. 
   Copy/paste the link into the window your dev tools is pointing to.
2. You are filtering and not including "Other", which is where 300
   level messages now appear.

Comment: 2 caught me by surprise. I was actually looking for those around the internet and couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: 2 for me as well. Saved me some time here...

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar, if not identical, outcome as described in the question.

I fixed this by adjusting Chrome Developer Tools > Network > Filter settings, Select 'All' as per the screenshot resources at bottom.

This once again displayed the 3xx messages in the Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools.

[Chrome Developer Tools > Network Tab Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axL6Q.png)

[Chrome Developer Tools > Network Tab After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WuKb.png)

Comment: In your "Before" screenshot, you just filtered the network requests to see JS requests only, requests with 3xx responses are categorized as "Other", "All" is all requests without filters, no magic there.